# cmake: use msbuild.exe instead of vs2013 use GENERATOR="Visual Studio 12 vs2013 Win64"

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, msbuild, cmake

**Can you specify from a batch file or edit a file under the cmake installation??**

I want to use msbuild.exe without visual studio IDE but I get this error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

I figure it's looking for msbuild.exe under an installation of the IDE but can't find it because there is no IDE. 
1) Am I correct in thinking that?

I want to specify the compiler, but it can't be through a cmakeList.txt and I can't change what's already set up in cmake.

2) can you install msbuild 2013 instead of vs2013 and still use cmake where GENERATOR="Visual Studio 12 vs2013 Win64"

3) if so, can you specify where msbuild is from a batch file or edit a file under the cmake installation?

using msbuild 2013 and generator is set from a batch file like this where vc_ver is 12 and vs_version is 2013:

```
set GENERATOR="Visual Studio %VC_VER% %VS_VERSION% Win64"
```

Comment: Have you tried to use CMake's [`NMake Makefiles`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/NMake%20Makefiles.html) generator?